# Odd behavior in WAS 7.0: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: servlets, nullpointerexception, websphere-7

I'm working with WAS 7.0 and I found this error:

```
[27/10/13 11:55:06:727 CET] 00000023 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper run [Servlet Error]-[class java.lang.NullPointerException: null]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:190)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1909)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1900)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:730)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3933)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

The thing is that it doesn't show up all the time but only with the servlets I've created recently (i.e. old servlets are working, but new ones throw this error). For this reason I've checked that everything is properly compiled and linked and I haven't seen anything different from the working servlets.

Any hints on how to further debug this issue or how to solve it are really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Río

Comment: Have you tried restarting Websphere? It could be an out of memory issue.

Comment: I've tried what you said and the problem is still there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a PEBKAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Java 6 included in WebSphere Application Server has the lost the fix for [Java bug 4256569](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4256569), which obscures the actual cause of the failure.  If this issue is important to you, I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.  I verified that this issue has been resolved in the Java 7 included in WebSphere Application Server 8 and later.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have already realized that each time something fails, I must invest a lot of time just trying to see what's going on. I'm forced to use this version however, so I guess I have to deal with it.

Comment: If you open a PMR with IBM, they should be able to give you a fix for WAS 7 that makes problems like this easier to debug.

Comment: Did you install the Java fixpak?  If yes, then perhaps it regressed again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Despite what it looks like, it is not a platform problem, I just forgot to initialize an ArrayList and hell broke loose. Hooray for such useful compiler '¬¬